# C# Avro json reading getting a Arithmetic Operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, json, overflow, avro

My setup is quite plain. I'd like to convert a kafka-read json byte array message to a C# object using avro.

I have a json schema from which I've been able to generate to the object cs file.

I then do a decoding by:

- taking a kafka byte array; converting it to memory stream
- using `BinaryDecoder.BinaryDecoder` on the memory stream to get the decoded version
- created a SpecificDefaultReader with object schema get the reader
- then apply the `reader.Read(objectInstance, decoder)`

My intent was to generate a cs object instance with the kafka message values inserted.

However, I keep getting either an `Avro.AvroException` or `System.OverflowException` saying

> Arithmetic operation has resulted in an overflow

However, I don't use integers or any arithmetic operations.

Any ideas on where the overflow is happening?

My schema generated cs file roughly looks like this :

```
public partial class NAME: ISpecificRecod
{
    public static Schema _SCHEMA = Schema.Parse(@"{""type"":""string"",""name"":""fieldNAME""}");
    public string fieldNAME { get; set; }
    /*followed by get and Put for schema and the field, with the Put casting it to System.String*/
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  Also, can you share a full [mcve]?

Comment: Here's the error snippet (this is as far into the stack trace that's provided). The Lib function ByteArrayToObject is what I describe above. Will edit to include

"Timestamp"|ERROR|Could not decode message: offset=31|ex=System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at Avro.IO.BinaryDecoder.ReadString()
   at Avro.Generic.DefaultReader.Read[T](T reuse, Decoder decoder)
   at "System".Avro.AvroUtils.ByteArrayToObject[T](Byte[] bytes) in "code location"
   at "ServiceConsumingKafkaAndCallingAvro".decode(KafkaMessage`2 enterpriseInventory) in "code location"